# React. How to get actual values from a state inside an asyn function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I'm beginner and I'm not sure if I solved the problem in a proper way.

I have a form with controlled components and I have to get values from these components in an async function to send them to a rest api backend. But If I'm trying to do it from an async function, I have got just empty values, because I don't have access to actual state of these component in async function (onSubmit).

I have tried to use a hook useEffect to solve this problem, it works, but I'm not sure if it a proper to do it?

```
  const [comment1, setComment1] = useState('');
  const [comment2, setComment2] = useState('');
  const [comment3, setComment3] = useState('');
  const [imageS3URL1, setImageS3URL1] = useState('');
  const [imageS3URL2, setImageS3URL2] = useState('');
  const [imageS3URL3, setImageS3URL3] = useState('');

  const [submitData, setSubmitData] = useState(false);

  const dataToSubmit = () => {
    const data = {
      comment1: comment1,
      image1: imageS3URL1,
      comment2: comment2,
      image2: imageS3URL2,
      comment3: comment3,
      image3: imageS3URL3,
    };
    console.log('submitData', data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setSubmitData(false);
    submitData && dataToSubmit();
  }, [submitData]);

  const onSubmit = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    Promise.all([
      //@ts-ignore
      refS3Uploader1.current.uploadFile(),
      //@ts-ignore
      refS3Uploader2.current.uploadFile(),
      //@ts-ignore
      refS3Uploader3.current.uploadFile(),
    ]).then(values => {
      setSubmitData(true);
    });
  };
```

A second approach without useEffect, it works too.

```
  ...  
  const [submitData, setSubmitData] = useState(false);

  const onSubmit = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    Promise.all([
      //@ts-ignore
      refS3Uploader1.current.uploadFile(),
      //@ts-ignore
      refS3Uploader2.current.uploadFile(),
      //@ts-ignore
      refS3Uploader3.current.uploadFile(),
    ]).then(values => {
      setSubmitData(true);
    });
  };

  const dataToSubmit = () => {
    const data = {
      comment1: comment1,
      image1: imageS3URL1,
      comment2: comment2,
      image2: imageS3URL2,
      comment3: comment3,
      image3: imageS3URL3,
    };
    console.log('submitData', data);
  };

  if (submitData === true) {
    setSubmitData(false);
    dataToSubmit();
  }
```

Maybe I completely wrong and there is another, more proper way to solve it?

================
full code

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
    import { ImageS3Upload } from '../src';
    
    const Example4 = () => {  
      const URL_GENERATE_S3_URLKEY = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/citytree/s3/generate_signed_url/';
      const SERVER_PHOTO = 'https://urbangis.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/';
    
      const resizerOptions = {
        enabled: true,
        autoResize: true, // otherwise resizing will be preform before uploading
        maxWidth: 1280,
        maxHeight: 1280,
        compressFormat: 'JPEG',
        quality: 70,
        rotation: 0, // rotation is limited to multiples of 90 degrees
      };
    
      const refS3Uploader1 = useRef(); // to be able to call method uploadFile
      const refS3Uploader2 = useRef(); // to be able to call method uploadFile
      const refS3Uploader3 = useRef(); // to be able to call method uploadFile
    
      const [comment1, setComment1] = useState('');
      const [comment2, setComment2] = useState('');
      const [comment3, setComment3] = useState('');
      const [imageS3URL1, setImageS3URL1] = useState('');
      const [imageS3URL2, setImageS3URL2] = useState('');
      const [imageS3URL3, setImageS3URL3] = useState('');
    
      const [submitButtonDisabled, setSubmitButtonDisabled] = useState(false);
      const [submitData, setSubmitData] = useState(false);
    
      useEffect(() => {
         setSubmitData(false);
         submitData && dataToSubmit();
      }, [submitData]);
    
      const onSubmit = async (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setSubmitButtonDisabled(true);
        Promise.all([
          //@ts-ignore
          refS3Uploader1.current.uploadFile(),
          //@ts-ignore
          refS3Uploader2.current.uploadFile(),
          //@ts-ignore
          refS3Uploader3.current.uploadFile(),
        ]).then(values => {
          setSubmitButtonDisabled(false);
          let result = true;
          values.forEach(value => {
            if (!value) result = false;
          });
          result && setSubmitData(true); 
          
          //if I call dataToSubmit from here, I will get empty values
          dataToSubmit();
    
        });
      };
    
    
    
      const dataToSubmit = () => {
        const data = {
          comment1: comment1,
          image1: imageS3URL1,
          comment2: comment2,
          image2: imageS3URL2,
          comment3: comment3,
          image3: imageS3URL3,
        };
        console.log('submitData', data);
      };
    
      // if (submitData === true) {
      //   setSubmitData(false);
      //   dataToSubmit();
      // }  
    
      const onResizeStart1 = () => {
        setSubmitButtonDisabled(true);
      };
      const onResizeStart2 = () => {
        setSubmitButtonDisabled(true);
      };
      const onResizeStart3 = () => {
        setSubmitButtonDisabled(true);
      };
    
      const onResizeFinish1 = () => {
        setSubmitButtonDisabled(false);
      };
      const onResizeFinish2 = () => {
        setSubmitButtonDisabled(false);
      };
      const onResizeFinish3 = () => {
        setSubmitButtonDisabled(false);
      };
    
      return (
        <>
          <form
            onSubmit={onSubmit}
            style={{ margin: '10px', padding: '10px', border: 'solid 1px black' }}
          >
            
            <p><b>4. Form, multiple components, autoUpload=False</b></p>
    
            <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
              <div style={{ maxWidth: '200px', margin: '10px' }}>
                <label htmlFor="id_comment1">Comment</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  id="id_comment1"
                  value={comment1}
                  onChange={e => setComment1(e.target.value)}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <ImageS3Upload
                  signingUrl={URL_GENERATE_S3_URLKEY}
                  autoUpload={false}
                  serverPhoto={SERVER_PHOTO}
                  resizer={resizerOptions}
                  onResizeStart={onResizeStart1}
                  onResizeFinish={onResizeFinish1}
                  ref={refS3Uploader1}
                  value={imageS3URL1}
                  onChange={(e: any) => setImageS3URL1(e.target.value)}
                />
              </div>
    
              <div style={{ maxWidth: '200px', margin: '10px' }}>
                <label htmlFor="id_comment4">Comment</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  id="id_comment4"
                  value={comment2}
                  onChange={e => setComment2(e.target.value)}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <ImageS3Upload
                  signingUrl={URL_GENERATE_S3_URLKEY}
                  autoUpload={false}
                  serverPhoto={SERVER_PHOTO}
                  resizer={resizerOptions}
                  onResizeStart={onResizeStart2}
                  onResizeFinish={onResizeFinish2}
                  ref={refS3Uploader2}
                  value={imageS3URL2}
                  onChange={(e: any) => setImageS3URL2(e.target.value)}
                />
              </div>
    
              <div style={{ maxWidth: '200px', margin: '10px' }}>
                <label htmlFor="id_comment5">Comment</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  id="id_comment5"
                  value={comment3}
                  onChange={e => setComment3(e.target.value)}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <ImageS3Upload
                  signingUrl={URL_GENERATE_S3_URLKEY}
                  autoUpload={false}
                  serverPhoto={SERVER_PHOTO}
                  resizer={resizerOptions}
                  onResizeStart={onResizeStart3}
                  onResizeFinish={onResizeFinish3}
                  ref={refS3Uploader3}
                  value={imageS3URL3}
                  onChange={(e: any) => setImageS3URL3(e.target.value)}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <input
              type="submit"
              value="Submit"
              style={{ width: '100%' }}
              className="button"
              disabled={submitButtonDisabled}
            ></input>
          </form>
        </>
      ); 
    }
    
    export default Example4
```

Comment: *I don't have access to actual state of these component in async function (onSubmit)* why is that, you would definitely have it atleast on submit event .... can you show all the code including the form too

Comment: Thanks, I have added all the code with the form.

Comment: I would suggest to have a single state object for all form fileds, give the `key` of the object same as `name` of the element for an easy update, and I'm not sure why you said they are all empty on submit ...